# C - Passing structures through function arguments

Tags: c, function, arguments, structure

I am asked to write a function that takes two values from the structure type and compare them. If they are equal, it wants me to add two other values from those structures and send this to another structure. It is also supposed to return a 1 or 0 through the functions name, so I defined the function as an int.

I have attempted to write a program that takes an employee's social security number and their wage, and then another employee's ssn and wage. If the socials are the same, it will combine the two wages and send them to another structure which contains that employees total wages.

I am getting errors every time I mention the function compare. This appears to be due to the arguments of the function. How can this be done properly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define EMPLOYEE_COUNT 4

struct ewage
{
       int ssn;
       int wage;
}

struct record
{
       int totalwage;
}

int compare(struct ewage s1, struct ewage s2, struct record *r);

int main (void)
{
    struct ewage e[EMPLOYEE_COUNT];
    struct record r[EMPLOYEE_COUNT];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < EMPLOYEE_COUNT; i ++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < EMPLOYEE_COUNT; j ++)
        {
            int success = compare(e[i], e[j], &record[i]);
            if (success == 1)
                        printf ("%d / %d | Record: %d \n", i, j, record[i]);
            else
                        printf ("%d / %d | DOES NOT MATCH \n", i, j);
        }
    }

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int compare(struct ewage s1, struct ewage s2, struct record *r)
{
       if (s1.ssn == s2.ssn)
       {
                  r->totalwage = s1.wage + s2.wage;
                  return 1;
       }
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Compiling error, runtime exception, or just the result is not what you are expecting?

Comment: Apart from the errors pointed out by Charlie Burns I'd like to point out that you only declare arrays of structs but never set any values to the actual structs the array holds. This might of course be because the code is unfinished though...

Comment: @C.R., they were compile errors. Charlie Burns identified them all and now it's compiling properly.

Comment: @jpw That is correct. I had not set values to the array locations because the program would not compile. And when I did try it later, I ran into issues with null values, which you alluded to. I initialized the values of every array element just now, and it's working seemlessly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need semicolons after your struct defintion

```
struct ewage
{
       int ssn;
       int wage;
}; // here

struct record
{
       int totalwage;
}; // here
```

record is not defined, I assume it's real name is r

```
int success = compare(e[i], e[j], &r[i]); // here
if (success == 1)
    printf ("%d / %d | Record: %d \n", i, j, &r[i]); // here
```

Finally, you need something to print with the final %d, I assume total wage here:

```
printf ("%d / %d | Record: %d \n", i, j, r[i].totalwage); // here
```

Now you can start to debug it ...

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea that structures ended with a semi colon, and I messed up with record and r, AND also forgot to specify a variable in the structure r. I'm relieved to see that I was on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

there are a few mistakes:
1.there should be a ';' after the definition of a struct
2.you shouldn't pass a type 'record' to your function compare,instead you should pass &r[i]